# Separate gitignore for specific branch?

Tags: git, deployment, gitignore

I am looking for a possibility to make a specific gitignore for a specific branch.

Here is the scenario:
I have currently a git repo with 3 branches. Development, Master and Production. And I am using Mina to deploy the production branch to our server / hoster.

But there is a problem, I can't install things on the remote production server and the project I am working on is using bower and less. So after deploying I cant run a bower install && grunt build, because there is no bower nor grunt on the server.

As I was working alone on the project I just kept the vendor bower files, the generated css and minified css in the repo. And could easily deploy.

But now I am working with someone else on it and I had to ignore at least the generated css and minifed css /js stuff, because they produce always merge conflicts.

So my idea was to create a special gitignore for the production branch, where the css and min.css are not ignored. So I can deploy it. But so far I couldnt find anything about it.

Comment: may be this could help.... http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files

Comment: Thanks, but not really, because it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Your .gitignore is a checked-in file. Could you just make changes on the production branch only, and check them in?